# Problem with lambda function as thread argument

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

I'm trying to launch a thread that receives a lambda function as an argument. However, I'm getting a compile error.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

template <typename lambda,typename val>
inline void func_thread(lambda func, val value){
    //Do something

    func(value);

    //Do something
}

int main(){
    auto lambda = [] (int v){
        printf("lambda: %i\n",v);
    };

    func_thread(lambda,5);

    
    std::thread ui(
        func_thread,
        lambda,
        5
    );
    
}
```

The problem happens when I try to compile the following lines:

```
std::thread ui(
    func_thread,
    lambda,
    5
);
```

I get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to
'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>,
main()::<lambda(int)>&, int)'
```

Just calling the lambda function directly works as expected: `func_thread(lambda,5);`; the problem is passing it to a thread.

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dG4354ndd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not enough information in your call to the `std::thread` constructor for the compiler to deduce what the two template parameters should be to resolve the call to the `func_thread` function template.

To resolve this, you need to specify the types of *both* template parameters. Thus, your call to the thread constructor should look like this:

```cpp
    std::thread ui(
        func_thread<decltype(lambda), int>, // Specify template parameter types
        lambda,
        5
    );
```